# Pandas Dataframe remove all rows that begin with a double quotation mark

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
index        text        
0            Test1       
1            "Test2 and more text"      
2            "Test3 and other text     
3            Test4
```

I want to remove those rows that begin with a double quotation mark.  The result should be the following:

```
index        text        
0            Test1           
3            Test4
```

I am aware of [startswith](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-str-startswith/) but for some reason it isn't working for me. Here is what I've tried:

```
my_df = my_df[~my_df["text"].str.startswith("\"")]
my_df = my_df[~my_df["text"].str.startswith('"')]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do

```
m=df.text.str[0].ne('"')
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: text, dtype: bool
df=df[m]
```

Comment: hmm, for some reason this isn't working. I'm trying to figure out if it is an encoding issue. The dataframe is utf8

Comment: @Neil If even this does not work , that is code problem , " may be not " ~

Comment: I think I see what is going on. The double quotation mark I'm checking is a straight quotation mark and not a typical curly quotation mark. I've never run into this before. Hm.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression

```
my_df[~my_df["text"].str.contains("^\"")]
```

Comment: this seems like it should work but it isn't for me for some reason. It isn't removing the rows.

Comment: it filters rows,  not remove them.   which do you want to do?   this definitely works in a jupyter notebook.  if you have other characters,  just extend reg expr `my_df[~my_df["text"].str.contains("^[\",\',~]")]`

Answer (score 0):

This might work

`df = df[df['text'].str.match('.*\".*') == False]`